# Android - Save audio in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, android-sharedpreferences

I am writing an app in which the user is requested to choose an audio file which I then receive as a Uri (I use Intent.ACTION_PICK).

How do I save the data so the next time that the app is opened it can use that Uri in MediaPlayer.

I tried saving in SharedPreferences with uri.toString() and loading with Uri.Parse but when I use it in MediaPlayer I receive an error of setData failed.

```
 private void SaveSettings(Uri uri) throws FileNotFoundException
        {
            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(APP, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
           editor.putString("uri", uri.toString());
            editor.commit();
        }

// when calling: _uri = LoadSettings();
        private Uri LoadSettings()
        {
            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(APP, MODE_PRIVATE);
            String str = pref.getString("uri", null);
            if(str == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return Uri.parse(Uri.encode(str));
        }

    private void PlaySound() throws IOException
    {
         if(!_paused)
         {
                _mp = new MediaPlayer();
                _mp.setDataSource(this, _uri); // this fails
                _mp.prepare();
            }

            _paused = false;
            _mp.start();
    }
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Please share the logcat and code where you have tried this...

Comment: Well tell if that what you try to put in shared preferences is the same as what you get out.

Comment: `return Uri.parse(Uri.encode(str));` ????? Why??? Just `return Uri.parse(str);` will do.

Comment: I tried the encoding since I thought it may help, but I tried without it as well.
I get the same uri when I load - content://media/external/audio/media/3500

Comment: OK, The problem was indeed the encoding, sorry..